# Replace value in a dataframe with a value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm doing a master's thesis on the Premier League and I have a problem.

```
>Chelsea
 Attacking duo HT     Attacking duo AT     HomeTeam    AwayTeam        
   X                     Yes               Liverpool   Chelsea 
   No                     X                Chelsea     Manchester Utd
   X                     No                Arsenal     Chelsea
   No                     X                Chelsea     Norwich

>Liverpool
 Attacking duo HT     Attacking duo AT     HomeTeam    AwayTeam        
   No                     X                Liverpool   Manchester City
   X                     Yes               Burnley     Liverpool
   No                     X                Liverpool   Chelsea
   X                     Yes               Arsenal     Liverpool
```

In this example I would like to know how to replace the Chelsea X value in the 1st line of the Chelsea dataframe with the corresponding value in the 3rd line of the liverpool dataframe ('No')

Comment: what are Attacking duo HT and Attacking duo AT?

Comment: so you want the first line in the Chelsea df to read `No  Yes  Liverpool  Chelsea`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.update` to replace `NaN`s with `non-NAN`s from another df

First change the `X`s to `NaN`s and set `HomeTeam-AwayTeam` as index

```
import numpy as np # if you haven't already

for df in (Chelsea, Liverpool):
    (df
        .replace('X', np.nan, inplace=True)
        .set_index(['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'], inplace=True) # so pandas can align the rows the way we need them
    )
```

Now you can [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html#combining-comparing-joining-merging)

```
Chelsea.update(Liverpool)
```